# MAC address when discovering networks

Tags: wifi-hotspot, mac-address

When your Android (11) device is in the process of discovering available Wi-Fi networks (e.g. before you actually connect to one of them), is your Android device exposing its MAC address to these hotspots/routers or is this search for networks done without utilization of MAC address? And if MAC is used, is it also randomized like it is by default when connecting to the network or is in this case using real MAC?

Comment: Wifi hotspots that are not hidden (SSID broadcast is enabled) can be determined by passive sniffing (nothing is sent so no MAC is used). Only if you have at least one saved hidden WiFi Android actively ping for this network. But nowadays I think Wifi should make use of a randomized MAC in such a case.